# How to pass variable string as an argument to Names Object

Tags: excel, vba, named-ranges

I'm using a code to identify a the name of a range and store it in a variable. Then, pass this variable using Names object to a Range variable to convert the string to a cell range. However, I'm getting Application defined or Object Defined error. What would be the correct way to do this?

```
    Dim Temp As String, Temp1 As String, Temp3 As String
    Dim Temp2 As Range
    Temp = "abcd"
    Temp1 = "xyz"
    Temp3 = Temp1 & Temp
    Set Temp2 = ActiveWorkbook.Names(Temp3).RefersToRange
```

I would want Temp2 to have a range value of A1:B5 corresponding to the named range xyzabcd

Comment: `Names(Temp3)` doesn't return a `Range`, it returns a `Name`. Add [`.RefersToRange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.name.referstorange).

Comment: On a side note, you cannot declare multiple variables as strings on a single line as you did. Use `Dim Temp As String, Temp1 As String, Temp3 As String` instead.